# Fuse 6.3 dbcp basic datasource

Tags: oracle, datasource, jbossfuse

I am not able to get dbcp2 working in JBoss fuse 6.3. 
The code given below works fine in Fuse container.

```
<bean id="oracleDSTest" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="hr" />
        <property name="password" value="hr" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="1" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="oracleDSTest">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/oracleDSTest" />
            <entry key="datasource.name" value="oracleDSTest" />
        </service-properties>
    </service>
```

But if I use `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` instead of `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` it fails with the following error:

> Error executing command: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Which version of oracle jar are you using?

Comment: ojdbc (11.2.0.0)

Comment: it took me some time to check: everything works fine on my machines. I'm using a slightly different version though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar` and the driver works in both configurations.

I tested it with a query from JBoss Fuse Console

```
jdbc:query jdbc/oracle 'select * from somewhere.sometable WHERE rownum < 5'
```

Check that JDBC and JNDI are installed

```
features:install jdbc
features:install jndi
```

You can drop an XML file with the following content into `deploy/` to automagically have a datasource deployed.

## OracleDataSource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="oracleDSTest" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.host:1521:SID" />
        <property name="user" value="UrName" />
        <property name="password" value="YourPasswrd" />
    </bean>

    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="oracleDSTest">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/oracle" />
            <entry key="datasource.name" value="oracleDSTest" />
        </service-properties>
    </service>
</blueprint>
```

## BasicDataSource

```
<bean id="oracleDSTest" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.host:1521:SID"/>
    <property name="username" value="UrName"/>
    <property name="password" value="YourPasswrd"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="1" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
</bean>

<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="oracleDSTest">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/oracle" />
        <entry key="datasource.name" value="oracleDSTest" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

## Classloading

Please mind that this version of Oracle JDBC driver is **not** OSGi ready.
To get everything to work under OSGi you may want to export Oracle classes from
the System bundle.
Copy `ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar` (or your version) to `lib/` folder of JBoss Fuse.
Edit `etc/config.properties` and add the packages to `org.osgi.framework.system.packages` property

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages= \
  other.packages.here, \
  oracle.jdbc;version="11.2.0.3", \
  oracle.jdbc.driver;version="11.2.0.3", \
  oracle.jdbc.pool;version="11.2.0.3", \
  some.other.stuff
```

Reboot and check with `exports | grep oracle`

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> exports | grep oracle
     0 oracle.jdbc; version=11.2.0.3
     0 oracle.jdbc.driver; version=11.2.0.3
     0 oracle.jdbc.pool; version=11.2.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked good. Also I need to add dbcp to the fuse container. osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4

Comment: @muru I'm using `mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp/1.4_3`, installed with `features:install camel-mybatis`