# Servicemix - Removing the text field from a log entry

Tags: logging, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am currently using ServiceMix to route between ActiveMQ queues.

```
 <bean id="kubeActivemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://172.9.9.6:30785" />
 </bean>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

      <route>
        <from uri="kubeActivemq:queue:///SMX_CONSUMES_FROM_HERE" />
        <to uri="log:EBIPMasterMessage?level=INFO&amp;maxChars=0" />
        <to uri="kubeActivemq:SMX_PRODUCES_HERE-2" />
      </route>
  </camelContext>
```

The custom logger that I am using is configured as follows.

```
# Root logger 
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, out, stdout, osgi:VmLogAppender 
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer 

# To avoid flooding the log when using INFO level on an ssh connection and doing log:tail 
log4j.logger.org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession=INFO 

# CONSOLE appender not used by default 
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n 

# File appender 
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n 
log4j.appender.out.file=/logs/servicemix.log 
log4j.appender.out.append=true 
log4j.appender.out.maxFileSize=1MB 
log4j.appender.out.maxBackupIndex=10 

# Sift appender 
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender 
log4j.appender.sift.key=bundle.name 
log4j.appender.sift.default=servicemix 
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender 
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %m%n 
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=${karaf.data}/log/$\\{bundle.name\\}.log 
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true 

# Log EBIP Messages for Master Data queue 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.File=/logs/ebip-master.log 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.append=true 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.maxFileSize=1MB 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.maxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.logger.EBIPMasterMessage=DEBUG, ebipMaster 
log4j.additivity.EBIPMasterMessage=false
```

As far as my root logger goes, a sample of the log file I get is as follows :

```
2017-08-10 18:10:24,137 | DEBUG | SUMES_FROM_HERE] | EndpointMessageListener          | 118 - org.apache.camel.camel-jms - 2.16.3 | Endpoint[kubeActivemq://SMX_CONSUMES_FROM_HERE] consumer received JMS message: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 11, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:CA00201262-61888-1502388591181-1:1:1:1:7, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:CA00201262-61888-1502388591181-1:1:1:1, destination = queue://SMX_CONSUMES_FROM_HERE, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1502388599084, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1502388624136, brokerOutTime = 1502388624136, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@4530e9b8, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = Jun's test message 1} 

2017-08-10 18:10:26,450 | DEBUG | SUMES_FROM_HERE] | JmsConfiguration                 | 118 - org.apache.camel.camel-jms - 2.16.3 | Sending JMS message to: queue://SMX_PRODUCES_HERE with message: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId = null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {breadcrumbId=ID:CA00201262-61888-1502388591181-1:1:1:1:9, CamelJmsDeliveryMode=2}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = Jun's test message 1}
```

As you can see the log entries output a `text` field. e.g. `text = Jun's test message 1`

Is there a way I can remove the `text` field from the log entries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a custom Layout? Just extend [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html#format(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent)) and override `String format(LoggingEvent event)` method.

In the overridden version just **copy** the data and remove the `text` header before calling `super.format(event)`. Be sure not to modify the actual value passed.

Then configure your custom logger.

```
# Log EBIP Messages for Master Data queue 
log4j.appender.ebipMaster.layout=my.custom.DoNotPrintTextPatternLayout
```

Since you're running in ServiceMix be sure to have a bundle exposing such class.
Take a look at this anwser: [Fuse 6.3 dbcp basic datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528974/fuse-6-3-dbcp-basic-datasource/44590103#44590103) regarding **classloading**.